# About convert office to PDF

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" to convert Excel to PDF, but when my source file size is large such as 10MB, it takes a long time...

```
    public static bool XLSConvertToPDF(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        bool result = false;
        XlFixedFormatType targetType = XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF;
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass application = null;
        Workbook workBook = null;
        try
        {
            application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            object target = targetPath;
            object type = targetType;
            workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(sourcePath, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            workBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetType, target, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true, false, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (workBook != null)
            {
                workBook.Close(false, missing, missing);
                workBook = null;
            }
            if (application != null)
            {
                application.Quit();
                application = null;
            }
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

1.Is there good suggestions or alternative components to use?

2.I know that there is Adobe API, but how about the efficiency?

By the way, I also want to convert docx or pptx to pdf.
Thanks a lot!!